I keep getting an error when trying to install an API on kaggle
Input: !pip install fredapi
Output: WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7ad1be4b4c10>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution')': /simple/fredapi/
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement fredapi (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for fredapi

